# list comprehension, avoiding the none return on animation nodes expression

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I'm stuck with an issue which is actually solved in the documentation of Animation Nodes [here](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/expression.html?highlight=expression) but as I'm still learning python I can't find the error.

This expression should append elements to a list after a condition:

```
[filas.append(x) for x in list if x == sector_name]
```

But as in the docs is explained the return will be `none` we have to add the list created like this:

```
[list.append(element), list][1]
```

but I can't figure out how to write my expression correctly, please some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension you have will return a list of `None`, instead you want the actual list `filas` after the appending was done. The documentation describes the case where you append a single element, so all you have to do is replace the first element of the dummy list with your list comprehension as follows:

```
[[filas.append(x) for x in list if x == sector_name], filas][1]
```

Note, however, that such expression is not required, you can use a normal list comprehension as follows:

```
[x for x in list if x == sector_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists can be joined with "+": 
So you make a new list (list comprehension) with all the x for which the condition is True and simply add it to the existing list.

```
filas + [x for x in list if x == sector_name]
```